# adding delays for a specific task without threading

Tags: python, function, loops, logic

In this code what I was trying to do is when `last_action == 1`, I wanted the LED to be switched on for 8 seconds before getting switched off. Also when `last_action ==  0`, I wanted the LED to be switched off for 8 seconds before getting switched on. The switching on and off of the LED is controlled by `use_door()` function. The code runs without error. But when the `last_action == 0`, when the LED is switched off, it won't be switched off for 8 seconds before getting switched on. It works fine when `last_action == 1`.

```
last_open_time = None            
last_close_time = None
last_action = -1


def openthedoor(set_accepted_list,set_list_ant_id,set_forbidden_list,set_accepted_list_frozen):
    global last_open_time
    global last_close_time
    global last_action
    should_remain_close = True 
    should_remain_open = False
    if (last_action == 1):
        curr_time = time.time()
        print "this is the last_action" + str(last_action)

        if last_open_time == None:
            last_open_time = time.time()
            print "time passed - " +str(curr_time - last_open_time)

        if (curr_time - last_open_time) < 8:
            should_remain_open = True
            print "should remain open"

    elif (last_action == 0):
        curr_time2 = time.time()
        print "this is the last_action for closing" + str(last_action)

        if last_close_time == None:
            last_close_time = time.time()
            print "time passed on closing-"+str(curr_time2 - last_close_time)

        if (curr_time2 - last_close_time) < 10:
            should_remain_close = True
            print "should_remain_close" 

    if(((len(set_accepted_list) >0) or should_remain_open == True) & (set_forbidden_list == set()) & ((set_accepted_list_frozen == None) or ((set_accepted_list_frozen & set_accepted_list)== set_accepted_list))):
        print"yes,open the gate"
        use_door(1)
        last_close_time = None
    else:
        print"no,close the gate"
        use_door(0)
        last_open_time = None
print "this is for shud remain open in 8 sec" + str(should_remain_open)
```

Comment: You might want to look into the idea of a finite state machine. It would be one approach you could you use.

Comment: @MartinEvans Can u tell me what is the problem with the current code?

Comment: @MartinEvans solved it. I was a simple mistake